# how to get child nodes in xsl

Tags: asp.net, xslt

here my code-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="ArrayOfLinkEntity" name="bindLink">
  <ul>
   <xsl:for-each select="LinkEntity[ParentLinkId=0]">
     <li>
       <xsl:variable name="linkId" select="LinkId"/>
       <xsl:variable name="child" select="count(/ArrayOfLinkEntity/LinkEntity[ParentLinkId=$linkId])"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="$child"/>
       <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="($child &gt; 0)">
           <a href="#"  data-flexmenu="flexmenu1" onclick="javascript:setPageLinkId({$linkId});">
             <xsl:value-of select="LinkTitle"/>
             <img src="../images/down.gif" border="0"/>
           </a>
         </xsl:when>

         <xsl:otherwise >
           <a href="#" onclick="javascript:setPageLinkId({$linkId});">
             <xsl:value-of select="LinkTitle"/>
           </a>
         </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
     </li>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**but I am getting $child=0 always.but there exists children.**
my xml structure-

```
<ArrayOfLinkEntity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <LinkEntity>
    <EntityId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</EntityId> 
    <LinkId>1</LinkId> 
    <SequenceNo>1</SequenceNo> 
    <ParentLinkId>0</ParentLinkId> 
    <LinkTitle>Home</LinkTitle> 
    <SubLink />
  </LinkEntity> ...  
</ArrayOfLinkEntity>
```

What should I do? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

> but I am getting $child=0 always.but
>   there exists children.

If by "children" you mean a `LinkEntity` with `ParentLinkId` child that is equal to the `LinkId` of the current node, the result you get is correct.

The only `LinkEntity` has an `LinkId` 1, but there are no `LinkEntity` elements in the provided XML document whose `ParentLinkId` is 1.

You need to show a complete (but the shortest possible) XML document on which your code exhibits this issue. Without being able to repro the problem, no one can give you a logical advice.

Answer (score 0):

From your following code:

```
<xsl:variable name="linkId" select="LinkId"/>
      <xsl:variable name="child" select="count(/ArrayOfLinkEntity/LinkEntity[ParentLinkId=$linkId])"/>
```

This occurs within a for-each loop where the only nodes being looped over are LinkEntity's with ParentLinkId = 0. But from your source XML, the value of LinkId = 1, and in your variable assignment for $child, you are selecting on LinkEntity's with ParentLinkId = 1, which don't exist in your source XML data.

If I misunderstood something please let me know, but from what I can see that may be the problem.

Comment: @ppp is getting those `LinkEntity` without parent in order to select their childs after. The input sample looks like a reduction...